# Ubuntu 20.04 frozen on splash screen

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2

I've got trouble on starting my laptop (simple boot to Ubuntu), the grub freezes on splash screen.

[Splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stoC7.jpg)

It's not a fresh installation and my laptop worked well before.

I've tried to repair the partitions with fsck, used grub utilities to repair and update it, tried a recovery mode, and edited grub to fix the poor nvidia driver compatibility with Linux

Have you any suggestions or things I have missed to fix the problem?

Regards

Comment: You can press Esc to see on what startup task the system is hanging. You may be able to login to a console terminal (and check `syslog`) by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 or F4...

Comment: Do you get as far as the GRUB menu? If so, try and boot into Recovery mode, or choose an older kernel, and see if you can get booted. You can also try `nomodeset` if you know how. Report back. Start new comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks for your replies
It seems that GRUB fail on rsyslog daemon service start, it's the last operation when i press Esc on splash screen. When i check the Xorg.failsafe.log, i have a "Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration." message
@heynnema, i've update the GRUB file on /etc/default to add nomodeset in the default command line, but nothing more appens

Comment: I need a little clarification. Are you able to get to the GRUB screen? How did you modify /etc/default/grub if you can't boot the system? Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema, i can access to the recovery mode by press Esc on Acer screen and access to the root console

Comment: Good. At the GRUB recovery screen, can you select an older kernel to boot to, and see if that fully boots up? Report back.

Comment: In root console mode, did you first remount / as a rw file system, and then modify /etc/default/grub with nomodeset, did you also do a `sudo update-grub` and then `reboot`?

Comment: re: *"edited grub to fix the poor nvidia driver compatibility"*... what did you modify here, and why?

Comment: Hello @heynnema, i aslo made this changes on /etc/default/grub
Next try is via an auto-repair from a live-usb

Comment: You didn't quite answer my questions, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Sorry @heynnema, i reading and answering from my smartphone, i can miss some messages. Well, selecting another old kernel do the same result, it freeze on the splash screen. So i made permanent change in the /etc/default/grub with nomodeset, update-grub and reboot, same result, it always block on the splash screen. Recently, i try to boot directly from a live-usb and... It freeze again

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.